# How to exclude a specific page from custom css in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web-deployment

I have inserted a custom CSS code inside my theme settings to make the site images look better and aligned.
All the pages work fine with a custom CSS view except the 'BLOGS' page.
Blogs page don't require that custom CSS code, it looks fine in default CSS code.
So basically I want to exclude the blogs page from my custom CSS

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {

.video-fit video, .video-fit iframe, img.back-image, .image-cover img, .has-format img, .has-equal-box-heights .box-image img {
    right: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 170px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
    font-family: 'object-fit: cover;';


}
```

This is my custom CSS code for the whole website which I have to exclude for the BLOGS page.
Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the css :not(selector) since the BLOG page has class blog in the `<body>` tag.

If you want to include different pages, just use the same method, but look at the body tag for other page specific classes.

`<body class="blog theme-YourThemeName woocommerce-js group-blog hfeed">`

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {

body:not(.blog) .video-fit video, body:not(.blog) .video-fit iframe, body:not(.blog) img.back-image, body:not(.blog) .image-cover img, body:not(.blog) .has-format img, body:not(.blog) .has-equal-box-heights body:not(.blog) .box-image img {
    right: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 170px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
    font-family: 'object-fit: cover;';


}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Howard E, this worked really fine..!
You're amazing!